# sequel never returns utf-8, just ascii-8bit

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding, utf-8, sequel

There is this mysql database I'm trying to connect to. DataMapper fetches everything nicely in UTF-8 but Sequel always returns strings in ASCII-8bit which produces errors with .to_json.

I have tried several things in order to get it to work.

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8  
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8  
DB.run 'set names utf8'  
Sequel.mysql 'db', (...), :encoding => 'utf-8'
```

I have gems: mysql (2.9.0) (tried without), mysql2 (0.3.11) and sequel (3.42.0)

The only thing that works is manually forcing the encoding on every string which is MUCH less than ideal.

Comment: did you db has ASCII-8BIT encoding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `Sequel.mysql2` instead of `Sequel.mysql`.  `Sequel.mysql` uses the old `mysql` driver instead of the new `mysql2` driver, and I don't believe the `mysql` driver supports encodings.

Comment: holy damn. I can't believe it was THIS simple. Thank you.

Comment: The documentations says nothing about this. I nearly went crazy. +100 if I could

Comment: I am using Sequel like this in the hope of using `mysql2` adapter, still its not retrieving Arabic characters properly: `Sequel.connect("mysql2://user:pass@localhost/the_database")`, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Encoding can be passed as do :

```
Sequel.connect("mysql2://user:pass@localhost/the_database?encoding=utf8")
```

Comment: Excellent, works for any connector