# How do I change my heroku postgres database's encoding?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, utf-8, sequel

I tried to insert this into my heroku postgres database.

> £

And got this error.

> Problem making a comment with ajax. PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3

I think my database's encoding is in CP850. How do I change it to UTF-8?

I'm using Sequel ORM

Using a Google search and seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28836980/337306), do I have to delete my database and create it again?

This doesn't work either.

```
Sequel::Model.plugin :force_encoding, 'UTF-8'

:encoding => 'utf8'
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump and recreate your DB?

Comment: I've created a new database and I still have that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot to change database encoding - not without some pretty ugly magic. The dump, and load is the most simple and safer steps.

Comment: I've tried with a new blank database and it didn't help.

Comment: I don't use a heroku, but I believe, there should be encoding setting for new database. http://robdodson.me/how-to-setup-postgresql-for-rails-and-heroku/

Comment: That link doesn't say anything about database encoding.